# How to store objects from session to List in Servlet

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, servlets, model-view-controller

Good day people.

I have really hard question to me which I spent whole day to think of today.
The first of all whole code you can get on this url `:https://github.com/Vadim32/RemoteWebContent`

Ok, now is the problem:
I need to make shopping cart of user orders. Where user can order events like: developing software or computer maintenance. 
So for this purpose I have servlet:

```
public class EventNewUserServlet extends HttpServlet {


    //-------------------------Variables------------------------

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        protected WebContentDAOIF webContentDAOIF;


    //-------------------------Servlet methods------------------  

     public void init() {
         /*Getting bean from spring ContextLoaderListener and inject it to webContentDAOIF variable 
           to use webContentDAOIF in this servlet*/
        ApplicationContext context = WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(getServletContext());
            webContentDAOIF = context.getBean("webContentDAOImpl", WebContentDAOIF.class);
        }



    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {


            List<UserEvents> userEventsList = new ArrayList<UserEvents>(2); //This list store all user orders 



        }
}
```

So I have `List<UserEvents> userEventsList` in doPost method which will store events which user order, like: ComputerMaintenanceEvent or SoftwareDevelopmentEvent, **they are all extended from UserEvents class**

On this jsp page:

```
<html>

        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
            <title>Order event page</title>

            <!-- Bootstrap css responsive-->
            <link href="resources/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
            <link href="resources/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">

        </head>

        <body>

            <!-- JQuery and Bootstrap file-->
            <script src="resources/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
            <script src="resources/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
            <script src="resources/js/jquery.scrollTo.js"></script> 
            <script src="resources/js/jquery.nav.js"></script>

            <h1>New user</h1>
            <form action="new-user-event" method="post">

                    <input type="hidden" name="userSessionId" value="${userSessionId}">

                <table align="center">

                    <tr><td>Event type:</td><td>
                        <select name="event_type">
                            <option>Choose event type</option>
                            <option>Computer Maintenance Event</option>
                            <option>Software Development Event</option>
                        </select>
                    </td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Event date:</td> <td><input type="text" class="span2" name="user_event_date"></td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Event description:</td> <td><textarea rows="5" name="description"></textarea></td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Additional Info:</td> <td><input type="text" class="span2" name="additional_info"></td></tr>

                    <tr><td>First name:</td> <td><input type="text" class="span2" name="first_name"></td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Last name:</td> <td><input type="text" class="span2" name="last_name"></td></tr> 
                    <tr><td>E-male:</td> <td><input type="text" class="span2" name="e_male"> </td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Address:</td> <td> <input type="text" class="span2" name="address"></td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Phone number:</td> <td> <input type="text" class="span2" name="phone_number"></td></tr>

                    <tr><td><input type="submit" value="Regester user"></td></tr>

                </table>

            </form>

        </body>

    </html>
```

User will order the actual events(will make orders).

*So the requirements are:*

- I don't want to make another servlet to store object in list and another servlet to store list of events in database.
- I want to collect objects of events first in session or just add them to list with no servlet(maybe somehow with jsp or javascripts), when user have for example add button on web page and he can add as many events as he wants in the list and after by submit button from form on same jsp page will trigger the actual servlet to save all collected events from list to database?

Is it possible to do so or not??

Thank you developers hope you will help me with some great tutorial or documentation to read.

Comment: Read about the MVC, or model2 architecture, and stick to that. Don't ever put Java code in JSPs. Don't ever put HTML code in servlets. Don't use the session for objects whose lifespan is not the whole session. That said, I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: Sir, Thank you for your reply. Please understand: I want to create and store objects right from my jsp page and store them in List<UserEvents> with no invoke servlet or controller. I do not want my page reload or do any forward or redirect when I click addToCart link, but object have to be added to the cart anyway. Is it possible to do so??

Comment: Yes, by sending an AJAX request to a servlet that will add the item to the cart. You can't send something to a server without having a component on the server to receive what you send. And such a component is called a servlet.

Comment: Ok. Got it. So, the page any way will be reloaded(refreshed) to refresh the view, right?

Comment: No. An AJAX request will be sent to the server, leaving the page as is is in the browser. But you need a servlet to handle this request: get the data posted, and add the item to the list. Read a basic introduction about AJAX.

Comment: Thank you JB Nizet for awesome advises.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion,you want to store events temporarily if add button is clicked. And finally only hit the submit button will update the previously temporarily stored events to database, right ?

The answer is simple, just think you shop in Amazon, you first add some products to carts, and the products you selected will be stored to cookie which stays in client's computer. And finally you checkout all the products you selected, here a servlet will read stored products from cookie and then persist them to the database. So I think you can follow this way.